# DENSE_RANK () trick Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am confused about DENSE_Rank function

so I have a code like this

```
select ID, date
From TABLE1
order by date
```

so It executes like this

```
ID  DATE
1   10/25/2016
1   10/23/2015
1   10/22/2014
2   10/11/2015
2    5/24/2014
2    5/21/2014
2    3/23/2013
3   10/21/2016
3    9/20/2015
```

my code is

```
    select ID, Extract(MONTH FROM DATE), DENSE_RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY ID,Extract(MONTH FROM DATE order by DATE) rank
FROM TABLE
```

it shows

```
   ID  DATE RANK
    1   10  1
    1   10  2
    1   10  3
    2   10  1 
    2    5  1
    2    5  2
    2    3  1
    3   10  1
    3    9  2
```

but I would like to show like below

```
  ID  DATE RANK
    1   10  1
    1   10  1
    1   10  1
    2   10  1 
    2    5  2
    2    5  2
    2    3  3
    3   10  1
    3    9  2
```

how can I code to execute above

Thank you so much

Comment: Do you really want to `partition by` [code that extracts month], or `order by` it? `dense_rank` will show the same value only if the rows are tied by the `order by` value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to order by the month (in descending order) rather than partition by them:

```
SELECT ID,
       Extract(MONTH FROM "DATE"),
       DENSE_RANK () OVER ( PARTITION BY ID
                            ORDER BY Extract(MONTH FROM "DATE") DESC ) rank
FROM   your_table
```